# Regexp Matching Hex Color Syntax (and Shorten form)

Tags: javascript, regex

Well, I'm pretty new on regex and in particular on JavaScript regexp.

I'm looking for making a regexp that match the hex color syntax (like `#34ffa6`)
Then I looked at the w3school page: [Javascript RegExp Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Then that's my regexp:

```regex
/^#[0-9a-f]{6}/i
```

It seems to work but, if I want it to match also the "short hex color syntax" form? (like `#3fa`), it's possible? I've tried using the character `|` but maybe I'm wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
/^#[0-9a-f]{3,6}$/i
```

would match `#abc`, `#abcd`, `#abcde`, `#abcdef`

```
/^#([0-9a-f]{3}|[0-9a-f]{6})$/i
```

would match `#abc` and `#abcdef` but not `#abcd`

```
/^#([0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}$/i
```

would match `#abc` and `#abcdef` but not `#abcd`

```
/^#(?:[0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}$/i
```

would match `#abc` and `#abcdef` but not `#abcd`

Have a look at [RegExp - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to learn more about regular expressions in javascript.

Comment: +1, was just about to post the final of your examples.  I would switch to non-capturing parenthesis `(?:)`, though.

Comment: @AndyE does the non-capture increase performance ? or just a nice to have !

Comment: @ManseUK: yes, although the difference would be negligible in most cases, it's just a "best practice" to get yourself into the habit of only using capturing parenthesis when you actually need to capture a subexpression.

Comment: non-captures are slightly faster (because their content doesn't have to be copied to the capture-group-buffer)

Comment: @AndyE OK - understood ... always learning with regex ... thanks

Comment: The uppercase letter is also acceptable, so the RegExp should be `/^#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}$/i`

Comment: @xcatliu that's covered by the i flag, it turns expressions case-insensitive

Comment: the last two patterns are marked unsafe by `eslint-security`.

Answer (score 9):

Try this :

```
/^#([0-9a-f]{6}|[0-9a-f]{3})$/i
```

`[0-9a-f]{6}` = 6 characters
`[0-9a-f]{3}` = 3 characters
`$` = end

Answer (score 6):

this should work
`/#[0-9a-f]{6}|#[0-9a-f]{3}/gi`

and for trying out regular expressions on the fly and learning it you can use this site
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 3):

You might want to incorporate 4 and 8 digit hex for #RGBA and #RRGGBBAA. I am doing this in a different setting where I'm using `match()` and `split()` to generate arrays.  I could not get all the variations posted by @rodneyrehm to work with the g flag and match, but the first (and most verbose) solution works if I list the character count in high to low order: 8, 6, 4, 3.

```
let rx  = /(?:#)[0-9a-f]{8}|(?:#)[0-9a-f]{6}|(?:#)[0-9a-f]{4}|(?:#)[0-9a-f]{3}/ig
let s   = "123 #AA22CC 100% #12F abc #A2Cd #aa11cc44 test 236px";
let arr = s.match(rx); // arr == ["#AA22CC", "#12F", "#A2Cd", "#aa11cc44"]
```

The MDN docs say that `(?:#)` should forget `"#"`, but it does not, and `(?=#)` simply fails.  What am I misunderstanding?
My final goal is to include the other numeric values in the array returned from `match()`.  I'm almost there...

Answer (score 2):

##### The possible Hex Colors are -

| Format | Example |
| --- | --- |
| #RGB | #F00 |
| #RGBA | #F005 |
| #RRGGBB | #FF7C00 |
| #RRGGBBAA | #FF7C0016 |

##### Regexp to match color `without` alpha

```js
let regex = /^#([A-F0-9]{3}|[A-F0-9]{6})$/i
```

##### Regexp to match color `with` alpha

```js
let regex = /^#([A-F0-9]{3,4}|[A-F0-9]{6}|[A-F0-9]{8})$/i
```